# How to make class or metatable for caluculate polynominals

Tags: variables, lua, formula, calculator, metatable

I am trying to make program which calculate Polynominals with Lua in LuaTeX.
For exsample.
  (2x^2+3xy+4)*(x+2y)=?

So I think start with Making Simple Class.

Next Code is for Single Variable Class without coefficient.

{"x",2} <--> x^2

```
do
  ItemS = setmetatable({ -- MetaTable 
  __mul = function(a, b)
      if getmetatable(a)==ItemS and getmetatable(b)==ItemS then
        if a.var==b.var then return ItemS(a.var, a.deg + b.deg) end
      end
    end,
  __div = function(a, b)
      if getmetatable(a)==ItemS and getmetatable(b)==ItemS then
        if a.var==b.var then return ItemS(a.var, a.deg - b.deg) end
      end
    end,
  __pow = function(a, b)
      if getmetatable(a)==ItemS and type(b) == "number" then 
        return ItemS(a.var, a.deg*b)
      end
    end,
  __eq = function (a, b)
      return (a.var==b.var and a.deg== b.deg)
    end,
  __concat = function(a, b)
      if getmetatable(a) == ItemS then return a.var .. "^{" .. a.deg.."}" .. b end
      return a .. b.var .. "^{" .. b.deg.."}"
    end,
  __tostring = function(a)
      if getmetatable(a) == ItemS then
        return a.var.."^{"..a.deg.."}"
      end
      return a.var.."^{"..a.deg.."}"
    end
    }, {
  __call = function(z, a, b) return setmetatable({var = a, deg = b}, z) end
  } )
end
```

Next I want to make Multivariable Class without coefficient.
But I don't know how to make Class with Lua Table...

I want to make class like table {{"x",2},{"y",3},...} <--> x^2y^3...

Please tell me how to make class for table...